# php while loop only executes if there is already first record in database for each userid

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function which works, but not exactly as expected. This is because `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` executes only if there is already one record inside a database for a specific user.

For example when I am trying to add first comment for user with ID=1 it pushes data into database table but it is not displayed. Then if I'll try to add second comment it finally displays it and any other record added after that.

Here is my function code.

```
function displayUserReviews() {

        global $link;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM user_reviews WHERE receiver_id='".$_GET['userid']."' LIMIT 10";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {

            echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>This user does not have any comments on his profile yet.</div>";

        } else {

            $queryUser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$row['sender_id']."'";
            $queryUserResult = mysqli_query($link, $queryUser);

            $rowUser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryUserResult);
            $userName = $rowUser['username'];
            $userId = $rowUser['id'];

        }

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $comment = $row['comment'];

            echo "<div class='col' id='userReviewsDiv'><em><p>~$comment</p></em>
                    <hr>
                    <span class='userReviews'>Author: </span><a href='?page=profile&userid=$userId'>$userName</a>
                </div>";

        }



}
```

Comment: That's because you are already fetching the first row further up, `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`, duh. Go read up on JOINs, and fetch the data in one single query.

Comment: Then research how to find out what's wrong and how to fix it. https://www.google.com/search?q=mysqli_num_rows()+expects+parameter+1+to+be+mysqli_result,+boolean+given

Comment: Okay I had mistake with my query. It's now all fixed. Thanks for help.